# Dax count where a value is higher than another value

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Hello I am trying to calculate and display a count for the number of times people have responded with a higher value in their second response from their first response. I have a table like the below

| username | field | response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| peter | #1 | 5 |
| peter | #2 | 4 |
| simon | #1 | 3 |
| lucy | #1 | 2 |
| lucy | #2 | 4 |
| aaron | #1 | 4 |
| aaron | #2 | 5 |

From the above table I would expect a value of 2 as there are 2 people (lucy and aaron) who have responded in both fields and where the response in field #2 is greater than their response in field #1.

Does anyone know how I can create this measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **measure**:

```
MyMeasure :=
VAR MyTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        Table1,
        Table1[username],
        "FirstResponse", CALCULATE( MIN( Table1[response] ), Table1[field] = "#1" ),
        "SecondResponse", CALCULATE( MIN( Table1[response] ), Table1[field] = "#2" )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX( MyTable, 0 + ( [SecondResponse] > [FirstResponse] ) )
```